# How can I reverse complement an excel file with multiple sequences?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to set up a script where I will input a .csv file that contains multiple sequences (1 per row) and get an excel file with the reverse complements as output.

Below is what I have tried so far.

```
import sys, getopt

def main(argv):
   inputfile = ''
   outputfile = ''
   try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
   except getopt.GetoptError:
      print('reversecomplement2.py -i <input csv> -o <output csv>')
      sys.exit(2)
   for opt, arg in opts:
      if opt == '-h':
         print('reversecomplement2.py -i <input csv> -o <output csv>')
         sys.exit()
      elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
         inputfile = arg
      elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
         outputfile = arg

complement = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'}
with open(outputfile, 'w') as final:
  with open(inputfile, 'r') as input:
      for line in input:
             reverse_complement = "".join(complement.get(base, base) for base in reversed(line))
             final.write(reverse_complement)
               

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
with open(outputfile, 'w') as final:
NameError: name 'outputfile' is not defined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you need to define `outputfile` somewhere before the `with` statement with the file name. Something like `outputfile = 'my_output_file.txt`. Looking at your code it looks like main should have `inputfile` and `outputfile` as parameters, and indentation from the `complement` line seems off

Comment: Thank you. Apparently, my indentation was just wrong.